# My offerflow is Angular11, can't get value 1 or 2 in html

Tags: javascript, angular

My task: The received value from service 1 or 2, depending on the value, change the styles in the html component. Using the ng-switch directive, I expect to compare the value received from the object with the specified template value. Styles are not applied. The main problem is that the styles are not applied

My component:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService, IProductListItem, SliderValueOptions } from 'common-modules';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { debounceTime, filter, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NgOnDestroy } from '../../core/services/destroy.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-item',
  templateUrl: './product-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-item.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [NgOnDestroy],
})
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() product: IProductListItem;
  @Input() doubleClickEnabled: boolean;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-output-on-prefix
  @Output() onAddToCart = new EventEmitter<any>();
  themeProperties: number;
  visibility: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _config: ConfigService, @Self() private onDestroy$: NgOnDestroy) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._config.marketplaceConfig.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe((config) => {
      this.themeProperties = config.structure?.theme;
    });
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<mat-card class="card">
  <div [ngSwitch]="themeProperties">
    <ng-template *ngswitchcase="2">
      {{ themeProperties }}
      <mat-card id="cardbackground">
        <a class="card__link" (click)="redirectToProduct(product)" (dblclick)="doubleClicked(product)">
          <div
            style="display: none"
            class="card__promo"
            *ngIf="product.priceWithDiscount && product?.promoIndividual?.percentDiscount"
          >
            -{{ product?.promoIndividual?.percentDiscount }}%
          </div>
          <!-- <b2b-modern-image mat-card-image [src]="product.photos[0]"></b2b-modern-image> -->
          <img class="mat-card-image" [src]="product.photos" alt="" />
          <mat-card-content class="card__content" [class.has-padding-top]="product && product['discount']">
            <div class="super-sale">супер скидка</div>
            <div *ngIf="product && product['discount']" class="discount">-{{ product['discount'] }}%</div>
            <div
              *ngIf="product && product.promoIndividual && product?.promoIndividual?.percentDiscount"
              class="discount"
            >
              -{{ product?.promoIndividual?.percentDiscount }}
              %
            </div>
            <ng-template #defaultPrice>
              <!--          <span class="price">{{product.price}} ₽</span>-->
            </ng-template>
            <div class="rating">
              <ngx-stars color="#ffd700" [readonly]="true" [initialStars]="product.rating || 0"> </ngx-stars>
              <span class="ml-3">{{ product.views || 0 }} отзывов</span>
            </div>
            <h3 class="name wrap-two-line" [matTooltip]="product?.feed" matTooltipPosition="above">
              {{ product | localize: 'name' }}
            </h3>
            <div class="а">
              <div
                class="d-flex align-items-center"
                *ngIf="product.priceWithDiscount && product.priceWithDiscount != product.price; else defaultPrice"
              >
                <span class="price old">{{ product.price }}₽</span>
              </div>
              <p class="price">{{ (product.priceWithDiscount || 0).toFixed(1) }}₽</p>
            </div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </a>
        <mat-card-footer class="card__footer">
          <a routerLink="/confirm-order" [queryParams]="{ products: product.id }" mat-raised-button color="primary">
            Купить сейчас
          </a>
          <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addToCart(product)">
            <mat-icon>add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-card-footer>
      </mat-card>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

The spelling of the [template switch statement](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase) is case sensitive, should be `*ngSwitchCase`.

Also the `ng-template` does not work in this case, you need to use `ng-container`

So please change your statements to this layout, and all should work:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="2">
```

also because you are using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you need to trigger the change detection manually for the ngSwitch.

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-85dfpe).

```
constructor(private _router: Router, private _config: ConfigService, @Self() private onDestroy$: NgOnDestroy, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._config.marketplaceConfig.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe((config) => {
      this.themeProperties = config.structure?.theme;
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <=== here, after setting the value
    });
  }
```

Comment: I checked your solution, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer as I missed the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`... you need to trigger change detection  manually in your case once the value changes

Comment: you're missing that this doesn't work cause of the `ng-template` directive. `ng-template` doesn't render anything. it's a template to be used elsewhere. it should be an `ng-container`

Comment: @bryan60 as you can see on my stackblitz it works, as it should, with the ng-template...

Comment: No it doesn’t. The template doesn’t render. You should probably look again as the `Template 2` part inside the `ng-template` tag is clearly not there.

Comment: agreed.. I had copied something out of the ngSwitch, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

change component to:

```
  themeProperties$: Observable<number>;
  
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.themeProperties$ = this._config.marketplaceConfig.pipe(map((config) => config.structure?.theme))
  }
```

change template to:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="themeProperties$ | async">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="2">
     ....
  </ng-container>
```

issues:

1. casing wrong on `ngSwitchCase` directive
2. `OnPush` change detection not running correctly, `async` pipe resolves
3. `ng-template` doesn't render to DOM. it's a template for use elsewhere. use `ng-container` instead.

Comment: @TheFabio you should double check your stackblitz. it's broken bc you're using ng-template improperly. you can also check the ng-template docs here: https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template